# How to update Protocol Buffer runtime library on Jetson TX1?

Tags: tensorflow, ubuntu-16.04, object-detection-api, nvidia-jetson, protobuf-3

I am trying to get the TensorFlow [Object Detection API](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection)  to train a Mask RCNN model.
Since I am using a [Nvidia Jetson TX1](https://developer.nvidia.com/embedded/buy/jetson-tx1), I installed TensorFlow 1.4 using the prebuilt wheel from this [github repo](https://github.com/lherman-cs/tensorflow-aarch64/).

While trying to run

```
cd <tensorflow>/models/research

python object_detection/model_main.py \
    --pipeline_config_path=${PIPELINE_CONFIG_PATH} \
    --model_dir=${MODEL_DIR} \
    --num_train_steps=${NUM_TRAIN_STEPS} \
    --num_eval_steps=${NUM_EVAL_STEPS} \
    --alsologtostderr
```

I hit the following the error:

```
[libprotobuf FATAL google/protobuf/stubs/common.cc:61]
This program requires version 3.4.0 of the Protocol Buffer runtime library,
but the installed version is 2.6.1.
Please update your library.  If you compiled the program yourself,
make sure that your headers are from the same version of Protocol Buffers
as your link-time library.
(Version verification failed in
"external/protobuf_archive/src/google/protobuf/any.pb.cc".)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'google::protobuf::FatalException'
```

It's telling me to update the `protobuf` library, but I have no clue how to do that, because I already tried to install the newest version (see below). Actually I don't even know who exactly is throwing this error. 
Hopefully someone can help me on this. Thanks in advance!

I installed the Object Detection API following the [official tutorial](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/installation.md), especially I installed a newer version of `protobuf` via

```
# remove old version
sudo apt purge protobuf-compiler

# download prebuilt protoc
cd ~/protobuf
wget https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases/download/v3.6.0/protoc-3.6.0-linux-aarch_64.zip
unzip protobuf-python*.zip
export PATH=$PATH:~/protobuf/bin
```

I think this installation works, because I get the desired output:

```
$ protoc --version
libprotoc 3.6.0

$ which protoc
/home/<username>/protobuf/bin/protoc
```

But also if I type

```
$ sudo find . -name "*libprotobuf*"
/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf-lite.so.9.0.1
/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf.so.9
/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf.so.9.0.1
/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf-lite.so.9
```

there is something installed by `apt`. Not sure if that has something to do with the error.

Running on:

- Ubuntu 16.04
- Python 3.5
- TensorFlow 1.4

Comment: In general, not being on a two-year old distribution release would be a start. Then again, all of Debian and Ubuntu (even at current releases) is still at [version 3.0](https://packages.debian.org/sid/libprotobuf-dev) -- apart from [3.6 in experimental](https://packages.debian.org/experimental/libprotobuf-dev).  You could rebuild this on your distro, or else find a PPA that has it.  I tend to have good success using a) current Ubuntu releaes (ie 18.04 right) mixed with b) backports where needed from Debian.